# Vuetify v-list with v-checkbox - v-model not working properly

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm trying to create a simple settings page with Vuetify. I use a *v-checkbox* inside a *v-list-item*, nothing special. However, my solution using *v-model* isn't working. See below.

Working example with *input-value* and *@click* instead of *v-model*:

```js
   ...
<v-list>
  <v-list-item link :input-value="someSetting" @click="toggleSomeSetting">
    <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>My setting</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
...


<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    someSetting () {
      return this.$store.state.settings.someSetting
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleSomeSetting () {
      this.$store.dispatch('settings/update', { someSetting: !this.$store.state.settings.someSetting })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Example with *v-model* - not working:

```js
...
<v-list>
  <v-list-item link v-model="someSetting">
    <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>My setting</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
...


<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    someSetting: {
      get () {
        return this.$store.state.settings.someSetting
      },
      set (newValue) {
        console.log(newValue)
        this.$store.dispatch('settings/update', { someSetting: newValue })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When I click on the item on my settings page, nothing happens. The setter of the computed property doesn't seem to be called as there is no output to the console. What am I missing here?

Comment: `:input-value="active"`  what's 'active' here and where is it defined?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the wrapping `<v-list-item-group>` element around all `<v-list-item>` elements

```
...
<v-list>
  <v-list-item-group>
    <v-list-item link v-model="someSetting">
      <template v-slot:default="{ active }">
        <v-list-item-action>
          <v-checkbox :input-value="active"></v-checkbox>
        </v-list-item-action>
        <v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-title>My setting</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
      </template>
    </v-list-item>
  </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
...
```

Or you can put the v-model in the checkbox:

```
...
<v-list>
  <v-list-item link>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <v-list-item-action>
        <v-checkbox v-model="someSetting"></v-checkbox>
      </v-list-item-action>
      <v-list-item-content>
        <v-list-item-title>My setting</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </template>
  </v-list-item>
</v-list>
...
```

If you have a list of multiple items and want to pass all the selected ones to maybe a database, the v-model should be put into the `<v-list-item-group>` element.

Also see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/ for detailed examples.